# Why are generic types unable to be declared as a return type in static methods?

Tags: java, generics, static-methods, raw-types

I understand why I'm unable to pass in the parameter `InterestPoint<M>` to the second method because of its static nature, but why does an error occur when I try to declare it as the return type? Removing the type parameter fixes this but then I'm left with the warning: *Raw use of parametrized class 'InterestPoint'*.

```
public record InterestPoint<M>(Coordinate coordinate, M marker) {

    public final InterestPoint<M> validate() {

        return this;
    }

    public static final InterestPoint<M> validate(InterestPoint interestPoint) {

        interestPoint.validate();
        return interestPoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because what is `M` supposed to be, you have no instance of the class that fixes the type. You can introduce a second generic type parameter just for the static method: `public static final <P> InterestPoint<P> validate(InterestPoint<P> interestPoint) {`.

Comment: You can write it as `public static <M> InterestPoint<M> validate(InterestPoint<M> interestPoint)`, but be aware the M of this static method is not at all related to the M you pass in the template of the wrapping class because the method is static and so is not related to the instance of the class itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `M` generic type parameter belongs to an instance, whereas a static method doesn't belong to a specific instance, but to a class. The way to have a static method return a generic type is to add a type parameter to it directly. E.g.:

```java
public static final <N> InterestPoint<N> validate(InterestPoint<N> interestPoint) {
    interestPoint.validate();
    return interestPoint;
}
```